# python opening files with \14 in the path

Tags: python, windows, path-separator

I am getting this error

```
[Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'S:\\Job Data$\\Jobs\\14-00060006\\Completed Files\\14-00060006_data.txt'
```

and others trying to open files.  I think it's because of the \14 and \13  etc but I am not sure.

Here is the code:

```
def crawl(path, phrase=""):
found_files = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith(".txt"):
            found_file = os.path.join(root, f)
            if phrase != "":
                try:
                    with open(found_file, mode='r') as text_file:
                        for line in text_file:
                            for part in line.split():
                                if phrase in part:
                                    found_files += 1
                                    print("\n\nFound one:")
                                    print(found_file)
                                    print(line)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
```

I am trying to find specific words in a directory tree, thousands of directories all prefixed with a number for the year, 14 for 2014 and so on and the cant be changed, how can I get python to read these files?

Comment: The problem might be the directory name `Job Data$`.

Comment: No, it opens the files, it's not the \14 either, but I get it with several hundred files, it's just that the first lot I tried were the \14's.  Some open, some don't.  The error is not every specific.

Comment: I don't know what the $ represents, I assumed it is a windows thing?  It's named that way by the IT department in another city and in their default mode not very helpful, you know the users are the enemy type of help desk :-(